# How to solve this inequality exactly?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to solve the inequality $$1-3\cdot 2^{1-4k^2}+3\cdot2^{3-(2k+1)^2} >x$$ *exactly* for $k$. In fact, I am looking for the smallest integer $k\geq1$ for which this inequality holds. I am particularly interested in the resulting $k$ for $x=0.5927$ (which is an approximation of the critical value for site percolation on the square lattice), but to keep things general we could take $x \in (0,1)$. I've tried to solve it, but I rapidly run into problems. My instinct is to take the $\log_2$ on the left side, but since it's a sum, things do not get a lot prettier. Rewriting to 
$$
2^{1-4k^2}(2^{1-4k}-1)>\frac{x-1}{3}
$$
also hasn't helped me a lot. Does anyone know how to tackle such an equation? Is it even possible to solve it exactly? I don't have (access) to Mathematica or similar software that solves equations exactly, maybe someone could get it to work?

Comment: I believe the exponent inside the parentheses should be $2-4k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%5E(1-4x%5E2)(2%5E(2-4x)-1)%20from%201%20to%205) $2^{1-4k^2}(2^{2-4k}-1)$ you find it rises rapidly from $-\frac 3{64}$ at $k=1$ to very near $0$ at $k=2$ (it is $-\frac {31}{2^{20}}$ there) so unless $x$ is very close to $1$ the answer will be $k=1$.  The term in parentheses approaches $-1$ rapidly, so for $x$ very close to $1$ I would take it to be $-1$ and solve the rest, which you can do explicitly
$$1-4k^2=\log_2\left(\frac {1-x}3\right)\\k=\frac 12\sqrt{1-\log_2\left(\frac {1-x}3\right)}$$  Now round up and check that it is large enough in the original equation.  If not add $1$ and you will be there.
[image]